# Flutter: Unable to install Runner.app on iPhone Simulator - Error 149

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, flutter-ios-build

I encountered an error while trying to run my Flutter application on the iPhone Simulator. Here's the error message:

```bash
Unable to install /Users/enkh-amgalan/Desktop/lesson/mobile/week-1/add_sub_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 524B6B86-9413-48BF-9408-288F75BDC9F4.
This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 149:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Failed to find service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support in session com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.524B6B86-9413-48BF-9408-288F75BDC9F4
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such process
No such process
Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install 524B6B86-9413-48BF-9408-288F75BDC9F4
/Users/enkh-amgalan/Desktop/lesson/mobile/week-1/add_sub_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
```

I attempted to run my Flutter application on the iPhone Simulator by using the flutter run command. I expected the application to build successfully and launch on the simulator. However, I encountered the error mentioned above instead.

Comment: There might be some issue in your Info.plist file, please verify if every tag is closed as expected or not.